# Alternatives to refcount for unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

In following code example, there should be exist one instance of struct `A` inside struct `B` as long as any object of `B` is living. Example works as expected.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "A() called" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A() called" << std::endl; }
};

struct B
{
    B()
    {
        std::cout << "B() called" << std::endl; 

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
        if( !refCount )
        {
            a.reset( new A ); 
        }
        ++refCount;
    }

    ~B()
    {
        std::cout << "~B() called" << std::endl;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
        --refCount;
        if( !refCount )
        {
            a.reset( ); 
        }
    }

    static std::unique_ptr<A> a;
    static std::mutex mtx;
    static int refCount;
};

std::unique_ptr<A> B::a;
int B::refCount(0);
std::mutex B::mtx;

int main()
{
    {
        B b1; //B::a should be created here
        B b2;
    } //B::a should be destroyed here

    B b3; // B::a should be recreated here
} //B::a should be destroyed again here
```

See also http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fea428254933ee5c

My question: Is there an alternative (threadsafe!) implementation without a refcount? Is this maybe possible to solve with a construct of `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`?

Comment: Unless this code was intentionally shortened, it asks for trouble, because it misses proper implementation of copy constructor and copy assignment for `struct B` (so that refcount is correctly maintained at all times).

Comment: Does your instance of `A` have to actually die when there doesn't happen to be any `B`s? The way you have things now you could simply have a `static A a;` that is only accessible to `B` objects. In your current code the `std::unique_ptr` is redundant because you have to manually delete its contents when your ref-count reaches zero.

Comment: @Leon: Yes, it was just shortened to minimum example

Comment: @Galik: Yeah, the intention of the question was, that there is no static lingering `A` if no `B`is living. Again, you're right, `std::unique_ptr` is actually useless and can be replaced by raw pointer

Comment: Then I can't see a better way to do things than you are doing them now. I suspect that even using a `shared_ptr` to manage the ref-counting is going to require external synchronization as it may or may not point to anything on construction. And you still have to manually manage the lifetime of the object.

Comment: So instead of a reference count, you want to use... a reference count. That's how `shared_ptr` works. Granted, `shared_ptr`'s reference counting implementation is atomic and robust, so using other people's code is not a bad idea. It's still using a reference count though.

Comment: @meddle0106: Please have a look at my post, and mark it as the exact answer to your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution wanted:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::weak_ptr;

struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "A() called" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A() called" << std::endl; }
};

struct B
{
    B()
    {   std::cout << "B() called" << std::endl;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
        if (!(ac =aw.lock()))
          aw =ac =shared_ptr<A>(new A);
    }

    ~B()
    {   std::cout << "~B() called" << std::endl;
    }
    shared_ptr<A> ac;
    static weak_ptr<A> aw;
    static std::mutex mtx;
};
weak_ptr<A> B::aw;
std::mutex B::mtx;

int main()
{
    {
        B b1; //B::a should be created here
        B b2;
    } //B::a should be destroyed here

    B b3; // B::a should be recreated here
} //B::a should be destroyed again here
```

which produces the same output as your example:

```
B() called
A() called
B() called
~B() called
~B() called
~A() called
B() called
A() called
~B() called
~A() called
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way to ensure that an object lives "as long as any object of `B` is living" is by keeping a refcount of `B` objects. It's the only realistic way to tell if there are any living `B` objects, if they are going to be arbitrarily created and destroyed as the program runs.

`std::shared_ptr` internally keeps refcounts, which are tracked atomically. It's probably a better idea to use those, rather than manually managing the refcount yourself; that way you don't have to meticulously implement all of the RAII constructors, or reinvent the wheel.